# The author of ‘commotion’

Tags: talmud-bavli, masechet-moed-katan

In the Talmud - Mas. Mo'ed Katan 16a, Pharaoh is called The author of ‘commotion’.

> As it is written: They called there, Pharaoh the king of Egypt [the author of] ‘commotion’; he hath let the appointed time pass by.

Was this a common title or term for Pharaoh and , 'As it is written' - where is this written?  Is there a specific text that is referenced here?

Comment: What translation are you using? I think you may be referring to [this passage](http://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.16a.4?lang=bi) (the only reference to Pharaoh I found on the page cited). Does that help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commotion is part of a verse in Jeremiah 46:17.

> קָרְא֖וּ שָׁ֑ם פַּרְעֹ֤ה מֶֽלֶךְ־מִצְרַ֙יִם֙ שָׁא֔וֹן הֶעֱבִ֖יר הַמּוֹעֵֽד׃‏
>
> There they called Pharaoh king of Egypt: “Braggart (or: Master of commotion) who let the hour go by.”

Though not everybody agrees that it refers to Pharaoh making a commotion, [Rashi](http://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.16a.4?lang=bi&p2=Jeremiah.46.17&lang2=bi&w2=Rashi&lang3=en) and the [Metzuda David](http://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.16a.4?lang=bi&p2=Jeremiah.46.17&lang2=bi&w2=Metzudat%20David&lang3=en) do explain the verse in Jeremiah 46:17 as referring to *commotion*.

**The commotion that Pharaoh makes is his loud bragging about his army's strength.**

Hat tip to [Shokhet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5323/shokhet) for finding the [passage](http://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.16a.4?lang=bi) you refer to (Moed Katan 16a).

Rashi:

> פרעה מלך מצרים שאון . שהיה מגביה קול שאונו תשואות להתהלל בחיילותיו

Metzuda:

> קראו שם. במעדכת צבא כשדים הכריזו לומר אשר פרעה מלך מצרים המרים קול שאון בגאוה ובגודל לבב הנה עתה העביר המועד ר״ל לא בא להלחם מערכה מול מערכה ביום המיועד והקבוע כי בא מורך בלבבו:‏